# URL concatenation with object returns bad request in Angular 4

Tags: angular, http

I have to send dynamic data to this API which has only two required params: id and text. I have an object with these keys bound to an input in the view and the id is hardcoded, but when I submit, I get a 400 status code:

The View:

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(f);"  >
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea  matInput placeholder="Text" 
    id="output-text"
    name="text" 
    [(ngModel)]="params.text"
    #userName="ngModel"
    placeholder="text"
    minlength="2"
    required>
    </textarea>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="block" (click)="onSubmit(f)" mat-raised-button>Submit</button>
  
</form>
```

The TS:

```
//INTERFACE
  results: response;
  
  //PARAMS

 params = {
    "handwriting_id": "8X3WQ4D800B0",
    "text": "",
    "handwriting_size": "",
    "handwriting_color": "",
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    }
    
    onSubmit(f){
    
       this.http.get<Response>('https://api.handwriting.io/render/png?' + this.params ,{
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
        btoa('STRSKVENJVBD0JDS:4ZN6VD256FEBHSM1'))
      }).subscribe(data => {
         this.results = data['results'];
        console.log(data);
  
        },(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
          } else {
            console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`); 
          }
        });
    }
```

But if I hardcode the URL, like this:

```
https://api.handwriting.io/render/png?handwriting_id=8X3WQ4D800B0&text=test
```

I get a 200. I'm missing something here; why the API doesn't accept dynamic values? Any help would much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending `this.params` to string, you need to set that in options object:

```
this.http.get<Response>('https://api.handwriting.io/render/png', {
    params: new HttpParams().set('handwriting_id', params.handwriting_id).set('text', params.text),
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('STRSKVENJVBD0JDS:4ZN6VD256FEBHSM1'))
}).subscribe(data => {...});
```

Or you could manually build the URL you want:

```
const url = `https://api.handwriting.io/render/png?handwriting_id=${params.handwriting_id}&text=${params.text}`;

this.http.get<Response>(url, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('STRSKVENJVBD0JDS:4ZN6VD256FEBHSM1'))
}).subscribe(data => {...});
```

Problem with your approach is that in JS when you try to append object to string, it will be converted to `"[object Object]"` so you were making requests to this URL:

`"https://api.handwriting.io/render/png?[object Object]"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Martin Adámek, but I get `this.params` underlined. Intellisense says that this type(params) has no propper ties in common with type Parameter:Codec

Comment: Try it now, `HttpParams` has different API than I thought. It should be `new HttpHeaders().set(key, value)`

Comment: Thanks @Martin Adámek, it worked with the "manual url". Cheers!